# Serial over TCP

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have a serial device connected to a remote computer and would like to transmit the serial data from this machine over tcp to another computer, both linux machines. Ideally, I would like to link two serial ports together between two computers by communicating over tcp.

I found this link:
[socat-ttyovertcp](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-ttyovertcp.txt), which explains that this is possible using socat. I've tried testing this by running a computer as a host with the virtual machine as the client; and although the code runs without syntax error, I do not know how to verify that they work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably use a raspberry pi.. Outside your quest really, but they are quite handy and run a *nix flavor.

Comment: One of the linux computers is a raspberry pi, I'm trying to connect the raspberry pi serial port to the other computer's serial port over tcp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option that you might not have looked into. You can use a [Serial over IP Adapter](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/Serial-over-IP/1-port-RS232-serial-over-ip-adapter~NETRS2321P) and then connect to the that device over your network. We use several of these to talk to PLCs and our phone systems.

Another one [here](http://www.usconverters.com/rs232-ethernet-converter) states the Virtual COM software supports linux. Where it will map a virtual COM device to the remote serial port.